# Access validation information from Angular 2 model-driven form?

Tags: validation, angular

I have an Angular 2 form that uses the template-driven approach that I am converting to a model-driven approach. Currently, the form uses a style like this:

```
.ng-valid[required] {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}
```

This marks all of the fields that have a required attribute with a green bar.

Now that I am moving this to model-driven, the control no longer has a "required" attribute. Is there a way to access the validation rules associated with a control (see below) with binding in the form?

```
  buildForm() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': [this.model.name, 
               Validators.compose([Validators.required,
                          Validators.minLength(4),
                          Validators.maxLength(24)])],
      'alterEgo': [this.model.alterEgo],
      'power': [this.model.power, Validators.required]
    });
```

Comment: I don't believe there's a way in the current release candidate.  I've got an open issue for this because I would also like to have attributes applied to form controls for the control's validators:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8175.  In the mean-time, ng-valid and the other validation classes will be applied based on the control's validation state and you can use those for css selection.

Comment: Yes, I can use the validation states to display error messages/color code for validity. But the original requirement was to mark the required fields.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to provide this logic by using my set of internal data structures and building a method like this:

```
  isRequired(controlName: string): boolean {
      if (Object.keys(this._validationMessages).includes(controlName)) {
        return Object.keys(this._validationMessages[controlName]).includes('required');}
      return false;
  }
```

The template then binds to this method, passing in the name of the control.